# How can I map a url to a specific port number on elb with route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-route53

Currently I have a ELB (spun up using kubernetes service 'LoadBalancer') that points a certain port let's just say 8100 to a node-port on my instances for an application that I spun up using helm/kubernetes. I can access the UI fine by using the public_dns_elb:8100.

Is it possible to make a route53 dns record at say test-app.com and then get to the application by doing test-app.com:8100 in my browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not something browsers support. You must use ports 80 and 443 for the defaults.

Comment: How is it I can hit the UI if I do the public_dns_elb:8100?

Comment: Because you told your browser explicitly which port to use :) just change the public port in your Service to 80 or 443 depending on if you are doing HTTPS (which you should be, so 443)

Comment: Definitely :) However shouldn't by that theory if I make a r53 record called test-app.com to the ELB, I should be able to just do test-app.com:8100 and hit the UI no?

Comment: No, as I said that is not how browsers or DNS works. The :8100 is not part of the host name, it’s part of the URI specification and is interpreted directly by your browser

Comment: Ugh, I feel stupid now. Just did some reading and you're right, DNS has no concept of port numbers outside of 80 and 443. By the way, small world but I think we might have a mutual connection. I'll message you on twitter